# Using PHP to execute multiple system commands

Tags: php, shell, command-line, exec

I'm working with SageMath and I am trying to use it in php with exec() or system(). They dont except multiple commands is what I understood from other questions on this but how would I be able to execute:

```
 sage
 sage: m = matrix(ZZ,2, range(4))
 sage: m[0,0] = m[0,0] - 3
 sage: m
```

so it can return the solution:

```
 [-3  1]
 [ 2  3]
```

Comment: you can create a sage script then call that as part of a command line argument. `exec(sage: load "example.sage")`;

Comment: How would I add in variables though? Like if I had a form on a page that returned the solution.

Comment: if you look at the 'Standalone Python/Sage Scripts' in the manual you will see you read from the command line.